# What is this weed whose leaves fold in at night?

Tags: identification, weeds

Can anyone tell me what this weed is? It's about two feet tall now and the leaves fold in like insect wings at night.

[image: green weed]

Comment: what part of the world is the plant located at?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like *Senna obtusifolia*, aka sicklepod. On page 25 of [this](https://www.daf.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0011/63875/IPA-Sicklepod-PSA.pdf) reference it says

> "The leaves of *S.obtusifolia* are photosensitive and the leaflets fold
>   upward by flexible petioles at night or on cloudy days."

"